# Tableau Filter by Measure to get "Top 30"

Tags: sorting, null, tableau-api

I'm reporting on TV spots my company ran and want to provide a "top 30" list of ads by highest CPA and lowest CPA.

**What I've done:** I created a similar report for "Top 30 TV Spots by Lift" by using a filter on the *timestamp* field.

Example of filter working as expected:

[image]

---

**Where I'm stuck:** However, this method is not working to filter for top 30 CPA and bottom 30 CPA. I'm ending up with nulls both ways.

Example of filter not working:

[image]

---

**What I need:** Report to sort by CPA to see both top and bottom performing TV spots. Exclude null and $0 CPA spots.

**Sample data:**

```
 Timestamp        |  Lift  |  Ad Cost  |  Ad Delta  |  CPA |
------------------|--------|-----------|------------|------|
 2016-12-09 12:00 |     0% |      $100 |          0 |      |
 2016-10-18 17:00 |    30% |      $800 |         40 |  $20 |
 2016-09-05 09:00 |   180% |        $0 |        100 |   $0 |
 2016-11-24 13:00 |    60% |       $50 |         10 |   $5 |
 2016-11-24 13:00 |   110% |       $50 |         25 |   $2 |
 2016-11-24 13:00 |     0% |       $10 |          0 |      |
 2016-11-24 13:00 |    60% |        $0 |         20 |   $0 |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my question because I've figured out a workaround. As far as I can tell, there is no way to actually filter by a measure.

I ended up applying a filter, sorting the column order, then counting the first 30 rows to find the number in the last row. Then I set the filter limit to this number. The filter was also useful for excluding $0's and nulls.

This solution will not scale for larger reports, but it did the trick this time.

Note: CPA renamed to CPS in the screenshot below.

[image]